# adding files to a treemap from a collection

Tags: java

```
for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            String fileName = file.getName().toString();
            System.out.println(fileName);
            String str = fileName.substring(5, 11);
            System.out.println(str);
        }
```

I am using the above code to get some sub string from the files. Now I want to make them separate lists according to the respective substring. How can I do that

```
List<File> group = mapFiles.get(str);
            if (group == null) {
                group = new ArrayList<File>();
                mapFiles.put(str, group);
            }
            group.add(file);
```

I am using this code to add them, but it was adding all files to the first sub string only.
Please help me.....

Comment: are you adding above code in a loop? If yes then show us whole code?

Comment: No, I am adding the second code in the first loop itself...

Comment: you need to show the actual code as it is actually laid out this is useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like :

```
    File[] files = /**** list of files */
    HashMap<String, List<File>> hm = new HashMap<String, List<File>>();

    for(File file : files) 
    {
        if (file.isFile()) 
        {
            String fileName = file.getName().toString();
            String str = fileName.substring(5, 11);

            if(hm.containsKey(str))
            {
                hm.get(str).add(file);
            }
            else
            {
                List<File> al = new ArrayList<File>();
                al.add(file);
                hm.put(str, al);
            }
            fileName = null;
            str = null;
        }
    }
```

To get separate list of file lists you can do :

```
public List<List<File>> getFileList(HashMap<String, List<File>> hm)
{
    List<List<File>> list = null;

    if(hm != null)
    {
        list = (ArrayList<List<File>>) hm.values();
    }

    return list;
}
```

This code is not tested. Hope this will work fine. Might need some modification according to your exact requirement.

Comment: No use it was adding all the files to a single hashmap

Comment: Yeas, but against different key. You can easily distinguish the lists stored against different key.

Comment: Sorry, they are adding to the single key..

Comment: np, let me know you have any additional issue.

Comment: Flow is running smoothly, but all the values are adding to the first key only.

Comment: Are you getting the same key always? If so, how are you planning to decide whether a file should be stored in the same list or a different list?

Comment: I have different sub strings right, so I need different lists according to them, but the code you had written is adding all the files to a single key, is this what you are asking??

Comment: Are you sure value "str" is coming different? Can you print it and verify?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help. I am able to solve it